# Bulk export on Azure / Export datatable into a file / Azure Scheduled Job

Tags: sql, azure, export, export-to-csv, bcp

1. I had a sql job which is scheduled on monday weekly. The purpose of that job is to run a procedure named "WeeklyStatus" which in turn get data from various table and then insert that processed data in a table and also save the same processed data in a csv file.
2. Now we have migrated to the azure database, but I don't understand how to do the same process in the same manner on azure database.
   how to create that job which will work in a similar manner.
   Can you please help me out ... or what are alternates to do that

step 1. SQL scheduled JOB

step 2. JOB step was ONLY one TO run ON monday PROC [WeeklyStatus]

step 3. defination OF PROC [WeeklyStatus] is below

**-- Description: Procedure used to Extract Call stats and activities from the past 7 days**

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[WeeklyStatus]
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @BegDate DATETIME;
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME;
    SET @BegDate=DATEADD(D, -7, GETDATE());
    SET @EndDate=GETDATE();

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..email') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Email;

        DELETE FROM dbo.WeeklyStatus;
        SELECT DISTINCT a.FName AS FirstName, a.LName AS LastName, a.MailingAddress, a.PhoneDay, b.MemberNum AS EmployeeID, b.BusinessUnit AS CostCenter, 
        b.DateEntered AS DateOfQuote, b.ApplicantId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         WHEN sel.RentalInsurance=0 THEN 'NO' END AS [Renter]
        INTO #Email
        FROM dbo.Referral r
             LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.id=r.id
             LEFT JOIN quote q ON q.id=c.id
        WHERE Agency='COM' AND DateEntered>=@BegDate AND DateEntered<@EndDate
        ORDER BY DateEntered DESC;

        INSERT INTO dbo.WeeklyStatus SELECT * FROM #Email;
        DROP TABLE #Email;

        DECLARE @COMCommand [VARCHAR](MAX), @COMQuery [VARCHAR](MAX), @COMDate VARCHAR(12);
        SET @COMDate=RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(GETDATE())), 2)+RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, DAY(GETDATE())), 2)+CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(GETDATE()));
        SET @COMQuery='SELECT * FROM dbo.WeeklyStatus';
        SET @COMCommand='EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp "'+@COMQuery+'" queryout "f:\usr\COM\Extracted_Data\CallDataExtract'+@COMDate+'.csv" -T -c -t"," -C ACP -r\n -S"ICT-SQL02\ICTEPIC"''';

    EXEC (@COMCommand)  
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Agent is not supported to Azure SQL Database to schedule and create job.

Suggested by **Masood Pehlvi** in [How to Schedule an Azure SQL Database’s Stored Procedure](https://global.hitachi-solutions.com/blog/azure-sql-databases-stored-procedure/)

To work around this azure give us **Process Automation**

***Step 1:***

- Create Automation Account

***Step 2:***

- Create runbook
- Click "Create" after entering a name and a description and choosing PowerShell as the "Runbook type."
- Into your Runbook editor, paste the script that follows:

```
Write-Output "Run started" 
#Instantiate the connection to the SQL Database 
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=servername.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=False;User ID=userid;Password=password;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" 
$sqlConnection.Open() 
Write-Output "Azure SQL database connection opened" 
#Define the SQL command to run 
$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120 
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection 
Write-Output "Issuing command to run stored procedure" 
#Execute the SQL command 
$sqlCommand.CommandText= 'exec [dbo].[storedProcedure]' 
$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
Write-Output "Stored procedure execution completed" 
#Close the SQL connection 
$sqlConnection.Close() 
Write-Output "Run completed"
```

***Step 3:***

- Create Schedule
- Click "Create" after entering the name, description, and suitable run times.

[image]

***Step 4:***

- Return to the Runbook and choose the previously established schedule by clicking schedule.

***Shedule runs***

***First runs***

[image]

***Next runs***

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ... this is exactly what i needed to automate process....

Comment: One more thing ... is this process chargeable or free on azure

Comment: @SAJIDBHAT Yes, it is a chargeable process.